# Android Studio Run warning : W/: Unable to open '/system/framework/WfdCommon.jar': No such file or directory

Tags: java, android, xml, xpath, warnings

I keep getting a warning in Run terminal of Android Studio that says:

> W/: Unable to open '/system/framework/WfdCommon.jar': No such file or directory
>
> W/art: Failed to open zip archive '/system/framework/WfdCommon.jar': I/O Error

The error is multiplied many times in a row. It shows while I'm testing an app on the phone with 5.0 android version and displays only when I'm parsing an XML file with xPath. Here's part of the code I'm using:

```
 XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xPath = factory.newXPath();

    MyArrayListOfData.clear();

    List<String> routeData = new ArrayList<>();
    String name;
    String distance;
    String value;

    try{
        NodeList dataParsed = (NodeList) xPath.evaluate("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr",new InputSource(new StringReader(urlToParse)) ,  XPathConstants.NODESET);
        for (int i = 0; i < dataParsed.getLength(); i++) {

            Element element = (Element) dataParsed.item(i);


            value = xPath.evaluate("td[1]/a",element);
            routeData.add(value);


            value = xPath.evaluate("td[2]/a",element);
            routeData.add(value);


            value = xPath.evaluate("td[3]/a/@href",element);
            value = value.replace("/przejazd/", "");
            routeData.add(value);


            value = xPath.evaluate("td[3]/a",element);
            routeData.add(value);


            value = xPath.evaluate("td[4]/a/@href",element);
            value = value.replace("/przystanek/", "");
            routeData.add(value);


            value = xPath.evaluate("td[4]/small",element);
            if(value!=""){
                routeData.add(value);}
            else {
                routeData.add("");
            }


            value = xPath.evaluate("td[5]/a",element);
            routeData.add(value);


            value = xPath.evaluate("td[6]/a/@href",element);
            value = value.replace("/przystanek/", "");
            routeData.add(value);


            value = xPath.evaluate("td[6]/small",element);
            if(value!=""){
                routeData.add(value);}
            else {
                routeData.add(""); }



            if(routeData.size()>0){
                MyArrayListOfData.add(new ArrayList<>(routeData)); }

            routeData.clear();
        }


    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        createToast("An error has occurred while parsing url");
    }
```

Is there a way to repair this problem? I've already set minSDKVersion of the project to 16 but it didn't help

Comment: It's just a warning. The app works normally?

Comment: Well, the app works, but it slows down because the Run terminal displays this 2 lines hundreds of times while using xPath on html. In other part of my app the same problem occurs in which I'm reading a big html file and it takes my application about 20 seconds to start working.